# Basic if endif not working and I'm puzzled

Tags: arduino-nano

I got this small code I'm trying things on for like an hour.

```
int receivers = 0;
#if defined(PPM_RECEIVER)
  receivers++;
#endif
```

And I just cannot get it working, It keeps returning a "'receivers' does not name a type" on line 4.

Comment: Question about C/C++ syntax.  This is counted as off topic on Arduino SE.

Comment: Maybe you mistyped receivers; did you copy-paste the code here or rewrote it? Of course then this code is written inside a function, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use commands like `receivers++` outside of a function.  That is runtime executable code, and has to be run from inside a function. Global scope doesn't get executed in the same way as code in a function.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, Thank you!